# Is this a bug in GoogleTest AssertionResult?

Tags: c++, googletest, sfinae

I've trimmed down the `EXPECT_TRUE` macro from [gtest.h](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class rai_class {
    public:
        static bool const value = true;
};

class AssertionResult {
 public:
  template <typename T>
  explicit AssertionResult(
      const T& success,
      typename std::enable_if<
          !std::is_convertible<T, AssertionResult>::value>::type*
          = nullptr)
      : success_(success) {}

  operator bool() const { return success_; }
 private:
  bool success_;
};

// Test type trait
bool test_rai_hash_implemented()
{
    return AssertionResult(rai_class::value);
    //return rai_class::value;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << test_rai_hash_implemented() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Without optimisations, it produces the link error "undefined reference to `rai_class::value'".

With -O2 it works ok. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: With the coliru link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d840e71525240865

Comment: There is a workaround in `AssertionResult(rai_class::value == true)`, but it's a little unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rai_class::value` is ODR-used (through `const T& success`), and so requires a definition.

```
bool const rai_class::value;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95019b7675ad63f0)

or use `constexpr` (which is implicitly `inline` since C++17)

```
class rai_class {
public:
    static bool constexpr value = true;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/381b6312915a82a5)

Comment: Thanks. `value` in our code was actually given the same assignment as the enum in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/257382/1958315. Your answer motivates changing the definition to an `enum`, which works.